# Remove WooCommerce Subscription recuring infos when recurring amount is 0

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We use WooCommerce Subscription and some subscription are payed upfront and some monthly. When buying a Subscription, WooCommerce displays additional information on the cart and checkout page. When buying monthly, this infos are welcome. But if a customer bills upfront, then this infos are not needed.

[image]

**Goal:**
We now try to hide the additional infos added by WooCommerce Subscription IF the recuring payment from the next payment is 0.

**Current code:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_is_recurring', 'hide_subscription_recuring_info', 10, 3 );

function hide_subscription_recuring_info( $is_recurring, $cart ) {

    // Check if recuring amount is 0

}
```

I'm a beginner and don't know how to access this values and hide the infos.

Anyone a idea how this can work? :)

Thanks.